# Why can't I import Qt3D modules?

Tags: qt, import, 3d

I'm going to start a project with *Qt Canvas 3D application*, but at the moment of importing modules it marks me error because they need those modules that are the following:

```
import Qt3D 1.0
import Qt3D.Shapes 1.0
```

Does anyone know how I can attach them? (Download link, download command or some other solution).
Thank you.

Comment: What error? Please, add the error you get and  your pro file to the question.

Comment: The error is when importing, these imports are marked in red. Once it happened to me with another module and I had to download it. I suppose this situation is similar.

Comment: @BrandCodes have you got this issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Qt are you using?
Qt 5.4 and newer come with Qt3D 2.0, so it might be that you are following some old tutorial or something, and trying to import Qt3D 1.0 because instead of Qt3D 2.0? 
If so, the API has also changed a lot so you would be better off finding an example using Qt3D 2.0 to get you started. Take a look at any examples you have installed that are using Qt3D, and take a look[Qt 3D QML Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-core-qmlmodule.html) for an example on importing v 2.0.

Comment: I am working with Qt 5.8, and in fact I have found an example to use Qt Canvas 3D application.  I suppose it is something old the example. I will try to find a more up-to-date example and check current imports to see if this causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcanvas3d-examples.html) are some examples for Canvas3D. It's for Qt 5.9, but I think most of them were the same in 5.8. They also come with the Qt creator, just search "canvas 3d" in the welcome screen